# ASTParser setting Environment manually

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to use the JDT's `ASTParser` outside of an eclipse plugin, which means I can't easily configure it through the Java Model (`IProject`, `ICompilationUnit` etc). Instead, I need to use [ASTParser.setEnvironment(classpathEntries, sourcepathEntries, encoding, includeVMPath)](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FASTParser.html&anchor=setEnvironment-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-boolean-). Which should be fine in theory, but I can't get the sourcepaths and classpaths to work.

Which arguments do these take exactly? I'd assume the absolute paths to JARs for the classpath, and absolute paths to all source (.java) files. However, the following does not work (error below):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] sourceFilePaths = new String[] {"C:\\Users\\Aljoscha\\Desktop\\workspaceba\\ExampleProject\\src\\examplepackage\\ExampleClass.java"};

    String[] classpathEntries = new String[] {"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_31\\src.zip"};
    String[] sourcepathEntries = new String[] {"C:\\Users\\Aljoscha\\Desktop\\workspaceba\\ExampleProject\\src\\examplepackage\\ExampleClass.java"};

    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
    parser.setEnvironment(classpathEntries, sourcepathEntries, null, false);

    MyFileASTRequestor requestor = new MyFileASTRequestor();

    parser.createASTs(sourceFilePaths, null, null, requestor, null);
}
```

That gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: invalid environment settings
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.getClasspath(ASTParser.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createASTs(ASTParser.java:993)
at asg.Foo.main(Foo.java:22)
```

Does anyone know what to pass to the setEnvironment() function?

Comment: The `sourcepathEntries` variable should most likely only contain directories. E.g. `"C:\\Users\\Aljoscha\\Desktop\\workspaceba\\ExampleProject\\src"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `classpathEntries` and `sourcepathEntries`  should be folder, JAR or ZIP.

BTW, the parameter `bindingKeys` of `parser.createASTs(...)` cannot be `null`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out once I can work on my desktop again. As for the bindings: The API docs are somewhat unclear on this parameter: Does this control which bindings are resolved/generated, or just which ones are given to the ASTRequestor? I'm fine with traversing the AST and calling the resolveBinding() methods as needed, but I do need the AST to have all necessary Bindings.

Comment: I'm not familar the JDT API. The answer is my concultion after running your code and checking the configuration in Eclipse. During my testing, JDT does not throw exception even the jar/folder of `classpathEntries/sourcepathEntries` does not exist. But it will throw NPE if `bindingKeys` is null.